# Is it possible to know who (what type) asked the dependency?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I am using an [Injection Listener](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/spi/InjectionListener.html) in order to make a post-inject initiation. Let's say that I create this annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public static @interface PrintValue {
    String value() default "";
}
```

Now I want every time an object of a `PrintValue` class to print this value. For example if the class is like this:

```
@PrintValue("Something")
public static class Foo {
}
```

, every time a Foo is being inejcted, my "post-inject" initiation is to print its value. However, I want to add an exception to this. I have tried a lot of things, but I was not able to achieve it.

If a class looks like this:

```
@PrintValue("Something else")
public static class Bar {

    @Inject
    public Bar(Foo foo) {
        System.out.println("Constructed a bar");
    }
}
```

I don't want Foo's post initiation to take place, because the object that asks the foo, is an object of a `PrintValue` class. In other words, this "Something else" "@Overrides" the `PrintValue` of Foo. The only way I can think of that makes me achieve it, is to get into the listener, the class of the object that asked for the dependency. See the full example and **notice the comment in the `InjectionListener`**:

```
public class GuiceListener {

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public static @interface PrintValue {
        String value() default "";
    }

    @PrintValue("Something")
    public static class Foo {

    }

    @PrintValue("Something else")
    public static class Bar {

        @Inject
        public Bar(Foo foo) {
            System.out.println("Constructed a bar");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Module module = new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(Foo.class);
                bind(Bar.class);
                bindListener(Matchers.any(), new TypeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public <I> void hear(TypeLiteral<I> type, TypeEncounter<I> encounter) {
                        if (type.getRawType().isAnnotationPresent(PrintValue.class)) {
                            encounter.register(new PrintValueInjectionListener());
                        }
                    }

                });
            }
        };
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(module);
        Foo foo = injector.getInstance(Foo.class);

        Bar bar = injector.getInstance(Bar.class);
    }

    public static class PrintValueInjectionListener implements InjectionListener<Object> {

        @Override
        public void afterInjection(Object injectee) {
            //get here who asked (its class) the injectee ??
            PrintValue printValue = injectee.getClass().getAnnotation(PrintValue.class);
            System.out.println(printValue.value());
        }

    }
}
```

If I run this, I get as output:

```
Something
Something
Constructed a bar
Something else
```

But the output I want is:

```
Something (printed because of the Foo foo = injector.getInstance(Foo.class))
Constructed a bar
Something else
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [`ProvisionListener.getDependencyChain()`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/spi/ProvisionListener.ProvisionInvocation.html#getDependencyChain--).  It's deprecated now but they give some example replacements.